# Why is my SQL UPDATE syntax giving 'ambiguous column name'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, ambiguous

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I am running the following UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE ReservationStay 

SET ReasonForstayCode = b.ReasonForStayCode

FROM MissingReasonForStay b

WHERE ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
```

The objective of the query is to update the column called 'ReasonForStayCode' in 'ReservationStay' Table using data from 'MissingReasonForStay' table. The look-up needs to be done using the 'ReservationStayID' columns of both tables.

Problem is that SSMS is underlining ReservationStayID at Line 4 of my code and when I run the query I get the message: Ambiguous column name 'ReservationStayID'

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It doesn't know which one. You defined b. Why not define a too?

Comment: I did. But it then gives me "incorrect syntax near SET".

Comment: Update a from RS a join RS b on ....? Sorry SQL servers not my dialect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because the `ReservationStayID` in your `WHERE` clause is not qualified and SQL Server is unable to decide which table that column belongs to.

Try this

```
UPDATE a
SET ReasonForstayCode = b.ReasonForStayCode
FROM MissingReasonForStay b
INNER JOIN ReservationStay a
ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this:

```
UPDATE ReservationStay 
SET ReasonForstayCode = b.ReasonForStayCode
FROM ReservationStay a
INNER JOIN MissingReasonForStay b
    ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID;
```

Comment: Thanks. I executed your code and got this error message:

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 4
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: If this is right then sql server is even more alien to me than I realised

Comment: Could you check which are the types of the `ReasonForStayCode` column of the two tables? I guess the first is smaller.

Comment: @gotqn I think you are right. I have an issue with the length of characters in the 'ReasonForStayCode' column of my 'MissingReasonForStay' table!
I will correct this and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i know this is an old question but figured i would post the solution since i don't see it here. you were almost there and correct about not being able to alias the table name in the update statement, so the solution is to just use the entire table name, using an alias is just to shorten things so you don't have to use the entire table name when writing queries anyhow.

```
    UPDATE ReservationStay 
    SET ReservationStay.ReasonForstayCode = b.ReasonForStayCode
    FROM MissingReasonForStay b
    WHERE ReservationStay.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
```

i believe this should work without having to change column names in either table.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ReservationStay a
SET ReasonForstayCode = b.ReasonForStayCode
FROM MissingReasonForStay b
WHERE a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
```